# Analysis hub report pdf export not working

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to export a report as pdf from the analysis hub, it says loading.. but nothing really happens. I have tried exporting with other formats and that seems to work just fine.
[image]
is there anyone else experiencing this? what I'm I doing wrong here?

Comment: It works for me, try to refresh page and try again to download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve my issue here is what i did incase anyone else faces the same issue
I just changed Automatic downloads to Allow in the site settings and then it worked.
[image]